# Flag button tooltip inaccurate

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, tooltips, flags

The tooltip for the `flag` button on the tools page always say "flag this question", even for answers:

[image: Screenshot of the tooltip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just pushed a fix, thanks for catching it.

Comment: to be deployed today